# Javascript - How to sum value of every row after press submit button

Tags: javascript, html

How to sum value of every row after each submit button event.

I need to calculate the total value of `<td>` .

Currently the code is calculating total table row.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells.length;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  x  ;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<br> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over your cells. One way you could loop over your cells collection is by using [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) if you firstly spread your `cells` into an array using the spread syntax (`...`). Then, you can use `.reduce` with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to add up the numbers within each table data element.

See example below:

```js
const displaySum = _ => {
  const cells = [...document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells],
  sum = cells.reduce((total, {textContent:num}) => +num + total, 0)
  
  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = sum;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br> 

<button onclick="displaySum()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @mplungjan now that I look at it I suppose you're right. While `reduce` is good for scenarios where you need to add things together in an array (and reach a total), I suppose using a regular `forEach` loop would be better in this case as it doesn't start off as an array but rather a collect :)

Comment: Liking the {textContent:num} though

Answer (score 2):

Get all the td iterate over them and add the textContent of the td. Convert the string to number

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sum = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(e => sum += +e.textContent)
  console.log(sum)
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>52</td>
      <td>52</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <br>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert `.cells` to array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to add the `textContent` of each cell.Make sure to convert the `textContent` to number using `Number()` or [Unary Plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) `+`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var cells = Array.from(document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells);
  let x = cells.reduce((ac,{textContent}) => Number(textContent) + ac,0);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  x  ;
}
function myFunction() {
  var cells = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells
  let sum = 0;
  for(let i = 0;i<cells.length;i++){
    sum += +cells[i].textContent 
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  sum
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr><td>52</td><td>52</td><td>12</td></tr>
</table>
<br> 
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want a simple way using no advanced methods. You can use

```
function myFunction() {
  var cells = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells
  let sum = 0;
  for(let i = 0;i<cells.length;i++){
    sum += +cells[i].textContent 
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  sum
}
```

Comment: Array.from and reduce is overkill. Any browser that can handle arrow functions can handle forEach

Answer (score 1):

With the least change to your code I use querySelectorAll and convert to number using +

**JS<2015 since OP is likely new to JS**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sum = 0, cells = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable td");
  // all browsers understand a for loop
  for (var i=0; i<cells.length; i++) {
    sum += +cells[i].innerText;
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText = sum
}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<br>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Same but in newer JS - no need to reduce

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sum = 0, cells = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable td");
  cells.forEach(cell => sum += +cell.innerText);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText = sum
}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<br>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Yeah `for` and `forEach` are more suitable in this case. +1